# Bootstrap grid display incorrectly in Galaxy Tab S

Tags: bootstrap-4

I just have very simple 3 columns using bootstrap grid which display correctly in all devices except Galaxy Tab S.  In Galaxy Tab S all the column stacking on top of each other, when it should be display in 3 colum

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>    

<body>           
          <nav id="header" style="height:100px; background-color: darkgreen">        
            <div id="header">
                <span class="welcomeName text-light display-4 ">Welcome John Doe</span>        
            </div>        
        </nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            One of three columns
        </div>

    </div>
</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

It should display as follows (Correct Display)

[image]

but in Galaxy Tab S it displays as below (Incorrect Display)

[image]

Have anyone experience this behaviour?   Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much better if you make use of flex

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

```html
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>    
    
    <body>           
              <nav id="header" style="height:100px; background-color: darkgreen">        
                <div id="header">
                    <span class="welcomeName text-light display-4 ">Welcome John Doe</span>        
                </div>        
            </nav>
    
       <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
          <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
          <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
          <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
        </div>
      
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks Otavio!   I think flex is a very good idea.   I have spent the whole day to make this bootstrap grid work in vain.

Comment: @Mike cool, you can read more about in documentation 
 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/